# Want to remove data from table based on info in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry I've looked around can't find any good examples for this question, I'm still learning SQL

I have 3 tables in the DB
All three tables contain the same Primary Key of Customer

```
Table 1 name is M 
Table 2 name is A
Table 3 name is S
```

I'm trying to make a sql script that removes data from Table M but as long as that customer does not exist in table A and also does not exist in Table S.

So for example this query returns any customers that exist in all 3 tables

```
SELECT M.Customer,A.Customer,S.Customer
From M
Inner Join A
ON M.Customer = A. Customer
Inner Join S
ON M.Customer = S.Customer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `EXISTS` operator with a subquery as the following:

```
DELETE FROM M
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.customer=M.customer)
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM S WHERE S.customer=M.customer)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ExbIb5qw).

Comment: thanks I see where what i was doing wrong.